# jQuery Layer Selector type plugin or customizable List View plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, layer, multi-select

I'm looking for a List View type of plugin compatible for jQuery 1.3. The functionality will be similar to a layer selector that is available in GIMP for instance.

The primary use is in desktop browsers and not mobile.

jQuery mobile list view seems to do the job but its for the mobile and seems to assume that its going to be hogging the whole screen. Think of this as a html multi-select but each list item is complicated. It should also be able to scroll without affecting the rest of the content on the page (which will be a map that the list view controls).

Essentially each list item will have a color picker, a textbox and a checkbox. Each list item controls a layer on an adjoining Google map. You may want to select a layer , deselect a layer, change its color, add a new layer and so on.

Comment: Does something like this http://jsfiddle.net/epinapala/5xwE8/821/ help? its using listview with a small hack, i know u dont want to use listview but nice write up here : http://www.elijahmanor.com/2011/02/dynamically-appending-elements-to.html

Comment: Why don't you try coding this functionality yourself? It doesn't look too difficult to implement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this: http://jsfiddle.net/yRxKK/1/

Pretty standard stuff here:

- div with overflow-y: scroll
- ul with block li's
- form with checkboxes and text fields for each layer
- color pickers from [www.eyecon.ro/colorpicker/](http://www.eyecon.ro/colorpicker/)
- jquery function for adding new layers
- selection change color effect

Hope it gets you on the right track! Note that the JS, CSS and image are hot-linked from eyecon.ro. Please change that if you use it!

Comment: ok.. are you looking for something beyond that? thought I covered all of the bases for the bounty.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to click on the bounty button! You definitely deserve the bounty.